# Strongly typed custom baseviewdata in a custom basecontroller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oop

In my project I have strongly typed viewdata in the spirit of the following:

```
AppleListViewData : ViewDataDictionary
  + SelectedTheme
  + ThemeList
  + SelectedApple
  + AppleList
```

Where the first four are re-occuring accross all the viewdatas because they are used in the site.master
To keep it DRY I elevated them into a BaseViewData class which the other inherit from.

Now all my controllers need to fill up these properties. Again, to keep it DRY I created a BaseController for my controllers that takes on this job.

```
BaseController : Controller
  + new ViewData : BaseViewData
  + FetchThemes
  + FetchSelectedTheme
```

The BaseController.ViewData is newed because it hides the Controller.ViewData 
All the controllers are responsible of newing up the viewdata at constructor time.

I'm essentially hiding the existing viewdata system and replacing it with my own.
This is where I feel I'm doing something wrong.
Any suggestions how I can make this work in a more elegant way?

Comment: It seems to me like you've re-invented strongly-typed views. I don't see the point. You can already have a strongly typed model if you care to.

Comment: But how do I use the existing strongly typed view with the concept of a base view?

Comment: You can use something like an action filter / before execute result to inject common view data, if need be.

Comment: You mean adding them in a weak way?

Comment: No, you add them any way you care to -- to a model property, to a custom property, whatever. Weak if that's what you want, strong otherwise. The point is that rather than doing this in a controller, do it in an action filter, since that follows SRP and doesn't create a parallel hierarchy.

Comment: Not sure I'm following you completely. I'm already filling the properties with an action filter, but I don't think that's the problem I'm facing. Where should those filters put the values? In the strongly typed viewdata? Where should this strongly typed viewdata be declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these items are always in your master pages, it may make sense to extract the controls which use the data and have a controller handle each one. Then in your masterpage use `Html.RenderAction` and output the user control with your data. This way none of your controllers get cluttered with information about the theme views, and anyone reading your code will easily see where the data comes from

Example

```
public class ThemeController : Controller{
  public ActionResult ThemeDropDown(){
     return PartialView(new ThemeViewModel(){ SelectedTheme = ..., ThemeList = ... })
  }
}


public class AppleController : Controller{
  public ActionResult AppleStuff(){
     return PartialView(new AppleViewModel(){ Apple = ..., AppleList = ... })
  }
}


<%= Html.RenderAction("ThemeDropDown", "Theme") %>    
<%= Html.RenderAction("AppleStuff", "Apple") %>
```

Comment: This could be a nice alternative to my system indeed. Gonna see if I can do this in my real app :)